# .NET, storing tail log outputs in memory, in a List<string>, frequent updates

Tags: .net, arrays, performance, list

In .NET (.NET Core to be specific), I am using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` library for logging.

I would like to display a live output in my web application.

I would like to implement my own `ILoggerProvider` that will store the ~200-or-so last logging entries.

I could store the results `List<string>` and `Add` new entries, and `Remove` old entries.

My question is, if verbose logging is turned on, what will the performance be like? Is there a better approach?

Would about a fixed `Array`, treated like a circular buffer?

Comment: As with many performance things, I would suggest creating the clearest/simplest version and trying it out. Then _if there is a performance problem_, you can find out exactly what it is. I don't think a `List<string>` or `string[]` usage is going to cause any perceptable performance differences for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd have a fixed array and a "current" variable kept % listSize

```
            int logSize=200, currentLog=0;
            var log = new string[logSize];
// Do whatever
            log[currentLog] = theThing;
// Bump
            currentLog = (currentLog + 1) % logSize;
```

Encapsulate in a class as required.

The reason for this is that lists and such have the potential to require a bit of re-arrangement when you start removing things from the start.